# Scanner not stopping from reading input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a program which reads strings from the console and stores the strings in random indexes of a String array. But the problem is that the program continuously asks to input and its not stopping. This is my program.

```
private static Scanner sc;
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] arr = new String[10];
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    Random rn = new Random();

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        int i = rn.nextInt(9);

        while(arr[i] != null) {
            i = rn.nextInt(9);
        }

        arr[i] = new String(line);
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        System.out.println(arr[x]);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Also after `10` inputs `System.out.println(line);` after the reading is also not printing.
Can anyone help me in finding the problem with my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read 10 lines:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    line = sc.nextLine();
```

And you try to store those 10 lines in 9 different indices of your array:

```
i = rn.nextInt(9);
```

So obviously, you'll loop ad vitam aeternam to find an available index for your 10th line.

Note that `new String(line)` is useless. Strings are immutable. So you can safely store the line itself.

Also, your strategy is not efficient: you'll loop again and again until you finally find an available index. A better strategy would be to fill a list of Strings, in order, and then shuffle it once it contains 10 lines, with `Collections.shuffle()`:

```
String[] arr = new String[10];
sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    arr[x] = sc.nextLine();
}
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because in your while loop it says while that element in your array is NOT null. Therefore, since it wouldn't be null, it would run infinitely. You should change it to

```
    while(arr[i] == null) {
    i = rn.nextInt(9);
    }
```

Comment: +1. I didn't spot the incorrect if test. But even with the correct test, it will still lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, your answer is also correct, I didn't see that either. Should you integrate your answer with mine, vice versa, or just keep it like this?

Comment: @PsyCode `while(arr[i] == null)` will be in infinite loop since initially all the elements in the array is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assignment to Array (arr) by inputting ten times from console, you should change (int i = rn.nextInt(9)) and (i = rn.nextInt(9);) to  (int i = rn.nextInt(10)) and (i = rn.nextInt(10);), because rn.nextInt(9) generate random Integer [0, 9), so when x = 9, your program can not out of the while loop and you input anything is useless(can not stop)!